# Python error [WinError 6] while using multiprocessing.Process with dill instead of standard Pickle

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, dill

I have this Process class which overrides standard multiprocessing.Process class in order to catch exceptions occurred in child process. Also I use dill and override multiprocessing standard Pickler because I need to.

```
import dill
import traceback
import multiprocessing

dill.Pickler.dumps, dill.Pickler.loads = dill.dumps, dill.loads
multiprocessing.reduction.ForkingPickler = dill.Pickler
multiprocessing.reduction.dump = dill.dump

class Process(multiprocessing.Process):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self._parent_conn, self._child_conn = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    self._exception = None

def run(self):
    try:
        multiprocessing.Process.run(self)
        self._child_conn.send(None)
    except Exception as e:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        self._child_conn.send((e, tb))

@property
def exception(self):
    if self._parent_conn.poll():
        self._exception = self._parent_conn.recv()
    return self._exception
```

Sadly, when I try to run child process where I run test function, it runs well until ANY operation  associated with Pipe. It can be closing, sending, anything it always crashes on:

```
TEST
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\<user>\Documents\Projects\sprinter\source\process.py", line 20, in run
    self._child_conn.send(None)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 211, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 285, in _send_bytes
    ov, err = _winapi.WriteFile(self._handle, buf, overlapped=True)
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

What is important to notice is that test function runs well but sending the info to the Pipe causes problem. Here is also the code that I run process from:

```
from source.process import Process

if __name__ == "__main__":

module = importlib.import_module('tests.api.test_api')  # Finding and importing module
object = getattr(module, 'TestApi')  # Getting Class from module
test_api = object() # Initializing object

process = Process(
    target=getattr(object, 'test_api_one'),
    args=(test_api,))

process.start()
process.join()
if process.exception:
    error, traceback = process.exception
    print(traceback)
```

This is caused by dill.. because if I use standard Pickler - it goes well without error. But I need to use dill due to other operations. Is there any workaround for this kind of situation? Why Pipe is having problem while sending info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the `dill` author.  The error you are getting doesn't seem to be coming from `dill`. To me it seems more likely that the replacement of the serialization objects in `multiprocessing` may not have been done as fully needed.

`OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid` is not an error that `dill` should generate... so I'd be surprised if `dill` is the root of the issue.  I'd suggest you trying to use `multiprocess` (I'm also the author) instead of `multiprocessing`. It's a fork of `multiprocessing` where `dill` has replaced `pickle`.  Then you don't need to try to hack the `ForkingPickler` object, you just import the `multiprocess` module instead of `multiprocessing`.

If using `multiprocess` doesn't solve your issue, then you may want to submit a ticket to the `multiprocess` GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: I can confirm that installing and using multiprocess did solve the issue. Catching exceptions works as intended. Thank you very much for your response.